# navigating between pages using radio buttons in winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

i'm trying to navigate between pages while toggling the radio buttons like the tab control. i've tries a few ways.Here they are

first the xaml

```
<StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="navigateto1" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Content="navigateto2"
                     Checked="RadioButton_Checked_1"/>

        <Frame x:Name="contentframe">

        </Frame>
    </StackPanel>
```

then the code behind

private void RadioButton_Checked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            var _frame = contentframe.Content as Frame;
            if (_frame!=null)
            {
                _frame.Navigate(typeof(navPage));
            }
        }

```
    private void RadioButton_Checked_1( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        var _frame = contentframe.Content as Frame;
        if (_frame!=null)
        {
            _frame.Navigate(typeof(navPage));
        }
     }
```

the frame is returned as null no matter what i do .. and it throws a nullreference exception on the content frame .. i've even tried including grid and other controls inside that frame even then i get a nulref exception.

what's the problem . why is it returning null? and is it safe to have a frame inside a page .. since it would be cascading two frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `_contentFrame`, not _`contentFrame.Content`.

```
var _frame = contentframe as Frame;
```

Comment: sure this worked ! but i was having some other problem that i just figured out ... actually this was just a mockup xaml that i did to replicate the problem ... my real problem arised because of using this xaml in a user control and i made a dependency property of type frame in the code behind and binded the content of the frame in this xaml to the dproperty.... Now i'm trying to use the user control to navigate to another page inside the user control ... just to be clear i'm bulding a tab control wher my user control is the tabbed interface that contains the buttns n fram to disply the pages